# bind make_shared with variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write the following factory class, but I can't find the proper syntax:

```cpp
template<class T, typename... TArgs>
class Factory {
 public:
  Factory(TArgs... args) {
    creator_ = std::bind(&std::make_shared<T, TArgs...>, args...);
    //      ^^^ some error around here
  }
  std::shared_ptr<T> Create() const {
    return creator_();
  }
 private:
  std::function<std::shared_ptr<T>()> creator_;
};
```

This is how I use the factory:

```cpp
class Foo {
 public:
  Foo(bool value) {}
};
class Bar {
 public:
   Bar(const std::string& value) {}
};
Factory<Foo, bool> f1(true);
Factory<Bar, std::string> f2("string");
```

These are the errors I get when declaring `f1` and `f2`:

```cpp
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::function<std::shared_ptr<Foo>()>' and 'std::_Bind_helper<false, std::shared_ptr<Foo> (*)(bool&&), bool&>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::shared_ptr<Foo> (*(bool))(bool&&)>}')
   creator_ = std::bind(&std::make_shared<T, TArgs...>, args...);
            ^

error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::function<std::shared_ptr<Bar>()>' and 'std::_Bind_helper<false, std::shared_ptr<Bar> (*)(std::basic_string<char>&&), std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>::type {aka std::_Bind<std::shared_ptr<Bar> (*(std::basic_string<char>))(std::basic_string<char>&&)>}')
   creator_ = std::bind(&std::make_shared<T, TArgs...>, args...);
            ^
```

What is the correct syntax I must use with `std::bind`?

Comment: `creator_ = std::bind(&std::make_shared<T, TArgs&...>, args...);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::make_shared` is declared like this:

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

As such, `std::make_shared<T, TArgs...>` will result in a function taking rvalue references, which won't bind to `args...`. A simple fix for this is to force it to take lvalue references by collapsing the reference:

```
creator_ = std::bind(&std::make_shared<T,TArgs&...>, args...);
//                                            ^
```

An alternative is to use a lambda instead, which is more readable:

```
creator_ = [=](){return std::make_shared<T>(args...);};
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I'd already tried the lambda approach before and I got `error: parameter packs not expanded with '...'` with gcc 4.8.4.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Did you write `return std::make_shared<T>(args);` or similar by mistake? It [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3f460e9022da772).

Comment: No, I just copied and pasted. I also get an error if I do `creator_ = [args...](){return std::make_shared<T>(args...);};` (`error: expected ‘,’ before ‘...’ token`).

Comment: @chronotrigger Make it `[&]` instead of `[args...]`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Bad idea, that would be undefined behavior very shortly.  That lambda outlives the local scope.  use `[=]` as TartainLlama suggested, not `[&]`.  You can even shave off a few more characters: `[=]{return std::make_shared<T>(args...);};`.

Answer (score 4):

So, a maximally efficient C++14 solution that doesn't use bind is actually awkward.

```
template<class T>
struct Factory {
  template<class...Args>
  Factory(Args&&... args):
    creator_(
      make_creator(
        std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{},
        std::make_tuple( std::forward<Args>(args)...
      )
    )
  {}
  std::shared_ptr<T> operator()() const {
    return creator_();
  }
private:
  using signature = std::shared_ptr<T>();
  using creator = std::function<signature>;
  creator creator_;
  // helper, to make a lambda with a tuple to unpack:
  template<class Tup, size_t...Is>
  static creator make_creator(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tup&& tup) {
    return [tup = std::forward<Tup>(tup)]{
      return std::make_shared<T>( std::get<Is>(tup)... );
    };
  }
};
```

this version has a few improvements.

First, no need to specify arguments you create the `T` from:

```
Factory<Foo> f1(true);
Factory<Bar> f2("string");
```

Second, instead of `f1.Create()`, we have `f1()`.  Invoking a factory clearly creates the thing the factory creates -- calling a named method is just noise.

We could go a step further:

```
template<class T>
using Factory = std::function<std::shared_ptr<T>()>;

namespace details {
  template<class T, class Tup, size_t...Is>
  Factory<T> make_factory(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tup&& tup) {
    return [tup = std::forward<Tup>(tup)]{
      return std::make_shared<T>( std::get<Is>(tup)... );
    };
  }
}
template<class T, class...Args>
Factory<T> make_factory(Args&&...args) {
  return details::make_factory<T>(
    std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{},
    std::make_tuple( std::forward<Args>(args)... )
  );
}
```

where we do away with the `Factory` type entirely -- `Factory<T>` just becomes an alias for a `std::function` that takes nothing and returns a `shared_ptr<T>`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cc85a8eca0dcfa2).

---

Now I find `details::make_factory` to be boring.

```
namespace details {
  template<class F, class Tup, size_t...Is>
  auto invoke( F&& f, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...> )
  -> std::result_of_t<F( std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::decay_t<Tup>>... )>
  {
    return std::forward<F>(f)( std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))... );
  }
}
template<class F, class Tup, size_t...Is>
auto invoke( F&& f, Tup&& tup )
{
  using count = std::tuple_size< std::decay_t<Tup> >;
  using indexes = std::make_index_sequence< count{} >;

  return details::invoke(
    std::forward<F>(f),
    std::forward<Tup>(tup),
    indexes{}
  );
}
template<class T>
auto shared_maker() {
  return [](auto&&...args){
    return std::make_shared<T>( decltype(args)(args)... );
  };
}

template<class T, class...Args>
Factory<T> make_factory(Args&&...args) {
  return [tup=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]{
    return invoke(
      shared_maker<T>(),
      tup
    );
  };
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b51c0332f4a7d0f), where we take the 'invoke a function from a tuple' and write it as `invoke` separately.

```
template<class T>
const auto shared_maker = [](auto&&...args){
  return std::make_shared<T>(decltype(args)(args)...);
};
```

would be slightly slicker, but [gcc 5.2.0 doesn't like it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48d5bca56de6c401).

Comment: If anyone lands here in 2017. template<class T>
const auto shared_maker = [](auto&&...args){
  return std::make_shared<T>(decltype(args)(args)...);
};Worked fine with clang (xcode 9.2) and g++.